# Why do my proximity mines sometimes prematurely detonate?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

When I play my Turian solider in multiplayer, sometimes when I launch a new mine the old one detonates.  Sometimes, I can spam them freely even right on top of each other.

I'd like to place as many mines on the map between rounds as I can, but often I can only place one.  Occasionally, I can place as many as I want.  I thought this might be a mechanic to keep players from spamming mines in spawn points, but this sometimes happens during the rounds as well.

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Premature detonation is nothing to be embarrassed about. Some studies have found that as many as 25% of Salarians experience PD.

Comment: Are you having problems with Premature Detonation?  Then you need KROAGRA, one pill will make you feel as virile as a Krogan!  KROAGRA, get it today!  Side effects include nausea, vomiting, dysentery, tourettes, and sudden death.  If you notice possible growth of a purple quad in an awkward place, stop taking Kroagra and contact your doctor immediately.

Comment: Damn you both for beating me to the punch on Obvious Joke. ):

Comment: @yx. Not sure I want to take virility advice from something named after a genetically sterile race.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be able to place proximity mines so close to each other.  Normally when you try to place a mine next to another one, the older mine will detonate.  However, I've noticed glitchy behavior with these things.  Sometimes a random mine somewhere else will detonate when you place a mine, and sometimes a mine will not detonate even when an enemy is next to it.

After taking a peek at the Coalesced.bin file for the proximity mines entry, I see the line:

> maxactivemines = 3

I guess if you have more than 3 mines then it'll detonate the oldest mine, but due to multiplayer graphic glitches sometimes you'll still see the mine there but it won't trigger anymore.

Comment: So it's a bug not a feature.  Any idea how to work around it?

Comment: @CaulynDarr not really, I suspect its due to general glitchiness of multiplayer and playing on someone else's machine.  I've noticed that it helps if you are the host of the game rather than joining someone else game.

Answer (score 0):

You are only aloud to have three active mines on the field at a time. It is written that way in the coalesced.bin ... However I can not answer why sometimes they explode and other times they do not. You can place a mine in a door way and than shoot a mine somewhere, when a monster runs through the door way it will not explode because it is no longer active ... So they might be trying to fix the graphic error in game by having the old mine explode so you are not lead to false hopes of it still being there to kill an enemy and its just buggy still.

Comment: this is wrong, I went and looked in coalesced.bin for proximitymine and it has maxactivemines = 3, not 1.

Comment: @yx At work, don't have the file in front of me to look, just knew there was a limit to it.